# How to set the opacity of titlerule and separation line in tcolorbox?

Tags: tcolorbox

I want a neat method to set the opacity of `titlerule` and the separation line of `\tcblower`. None of the keys mentioned in `tcolorbox` (page 536 for version 6.0.1) works.

For `titlerule`, this is possible by

```
titlerule style=SpringGreen3!75
```

For the separation line

```
segmentation code={\path[draw=green, dash dot, opacity=0.75] (segmentation.west) -- (segmentation.east);}
```

Is it possible to modify it by keys provided by `tcolorbox` itself? I want this because I define custom `tcolorbox` using `\tcbset` and want all opacity specifications in one place

```
\documentclass[11pt, a4paper]{book}

\usepackage[x11names]{xcolor}

\usepackage{blindtext}

\usepackage{tcolorbox}
\tcbuselibrary{skins}

\begin{document}

\begin{tcolorbox}[title={Transparent box}, enhanced jigsaw, titlerule style=SpringGreen3!75,
    segmentation code={\path[draw=green, dash dot, opacity=0.75] (segmentation.west) -- (segmentation.east);}, opacitylower=0
    ]
    
    \blindtext[1]
    \tcblower
    \blindtext[1]
    
\end{tcolorbox}
    
\end{document}
```

Comment: As far as I can tell using LuaLaTeX to compile your code the separation line respons to changes its `opacity`. When I change the `titlerule style` to `titlerule style={SpringGreen3!75, opacity=0.5}` that rule also responds to changes in opacity. So I am not sure whether I fully understand your question.

Comment: @alchemist. Excellent suggestion. This solves the opacity issue of `titlerule`. In fact, I get the result I want. I am just asking whether key pairs are available for `titlerule` and segmentation lines

Comment: I doubt you can set the opacity of both rules in one command.  `tcolorbox` is strictly modular build so you can manipulate about every aspect of every block independently. IMHO that is one of the strong points of that package.